# get the current frame of video c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, video

I am using visual studio.
I need to write a c++ dll, that plays video (h265 codec) in the background. The video shouldn't been seen, only the sound should be heard. I need to catch every frame and gives it to the host application.

I couldn't find a simple API that let me access the current frame of a player.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You've got a multi-media stream with both video frames and audio samples. The _video frames_ don't need to be seen but do need to be passed to an application. The audio samples should be heard, but not passed to the application. That sounds odd to me. Typically these two streams are synchronized but you'd lose the synchronization.

Comment: I think I won't lose the synchronization.
The application would ask me to give her the current frame. If something will take more time I will lose frames, but I can live with this. So the bad scenario is, a little dilay and frame loses.

Comment: Humans are quite sensitive to video/audio desynchronization. Even a half-frame delay is noticeable. Note that frame loss is a bandwidth problem, but synchronization is a latency problem.

Comment: I am not going to play a movie. I am going to play a little animation, so a little delay will be ok with the specific animations.

Answer (score 0):

This question is very broad, but, there are three choices:

1. [libVLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/libvlc.html) - easy to use and implement, but you don't have full access (but for your requirements, it should be enough)
2. [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) - you can spawn the ffmpeg command line tool and just get play audio output. This should be easy. If you want more control, you can use ffmpeg as library, what is kinda hard to use and implement, but you have full control over process of decoding and playback
3. [gstreamer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) - same as ffmpeg

Comment: I have tried to use libvlcpp without success. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67193943/libvlcpp-with-visual-studio).

I know how to use the ffmpeg command line tool. But, as I understand it, It runs in a different process, so I can't access the current frame. I start looking at using it as a library and it seems too hard for me, so I wonder if there is a simpler way